# Communication between python script and Arduino sketch

Tags: arduino-yun

I'm trying to transfer data beetween the two scripts. I'm already using the YunMesseger library (https://github.com/plotly/YunMessenger). But it only make the

Arduino -> Python

communication.
I would like to know how to make the reverse way.

I would like to point that I'm search for a solution that doesn't involve the use of the Bridge, because I don't want to have concurrency problems.

Comment: What do you mean by concurrency problems? For example, if you use bridge's mailbox, I'm pretty sure that messages from multiple sources just go into a queue on the Linux side, and the 32u4 can check this queue at it's leisure.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [spacebrew](http://docs.spacebrew.cc/). This is a cloud-based service, however you can run your own [server](https://github.com/spacebrew/spacebrew) which is based on node.js, so it should work on the Yun.

Your Arduino can then send or receive data using [yunSpacebrew](https://github.com/julioterra/yunSpacebrew), and you can connect it to python using [pySpacebrew](https://github.com/Spacebrew/pySpacebrew). This is a pure python library, so it ought to run fine on the Yun.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm aware of spacebrew, however I'm trying to build a service similar to theirs but integrated with other solutions I'm developing. That's why I need to know how to make this communication. Looking at their source files I saw that they use Console.read() in the arduino part, but I couldn't find how they do the python part.